# GetStream- How to sort the feed activity by descending order of likes?

Tags: getstream-io

I have 10 activity feeds, each feed as a different likes count, need to show the activity feed in descending order by likes count,
how to implement that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to retrieve total likes count for all activities in each feed and sort based on that?

Comment: no i need a likescount for each activity,for example- post1: had a 18likes and post2: had a 20 likes.If  i see the activity feed, the order should be post2 and post1. how to filter like that?

Answer (score 0):

Reaction counts are available for enriched activities. At the moment Stream doesn't support feed ranking based on reaction data but you can sort the activities yourself after you retrieved them from server:

```java
List<EnrichedActivity> activities = client.flatFeed("user", "alice")
        .getEnrichedActivities(new EnrichmentFlags().withReactionCounts())
        .get();

activities.sort((a, b) -> {
    int aLikes = a.getReactionCounts().getOrDefault("like", 0).intValue();
    int bLikes = b.getReactionCounts().getOrDefault("like", 0).intValue();
    return aLikes - bLikes;
});
```